# react-three-fiber shader uv wrong when inside component

Tags: reactjs, three.js, shader, react-three-fiber, react-flow

I'm trying to modify an example from react-flow-renderer ([React Flow Audio](https://reactflow.dev/blog/react-flow-and-the-web-audio-api/)) to render a shader inside each node. For that, I have a test shader that outputs the UVs, but it doesn't look right when inside a node, because not all the spectrum of colors is visible. However, if I use that same shader (that is exported as a functional component) directly in the `index.js`, it does render as expected.

Here is a sandbox recreating the problem: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shadertest-mnle1f?file=/index.js). Commenting lines 11 or 12 in `index.js` shows the situation. Here are some snapshots:

[image: shader inside node not rendering as expected]

[image: shader in index rendering as expected]

I've tried everything but I can't figure out the problem. I want to use that canvases for raymarching, and the results are well rendered besides that are translated off the center of the canvas.

I have also tried other libraries to render the shaders, like `shadertoy-react` or `gl-react`, but I get the error:

```
Failed to execute 'shaderSource' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLShader'."
```

Any help is appreciated.