# Can't render any shader in React: `Failed to execute 'shaderSource'`

Tags: reactjs, webgl, react-three-fiber, shadertoy

I'm trying to render a simple shader, but with every library I use (`gl-react`, `shadertoy-react`, etc), i get the error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'shaderSource' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLShader'.
    at compileShader (shader-cache.js:55:1)
    at proto.getShaderReference (shader-cache.js:75:1)
    at Object.getShaderReference [as shader] (shader-cache.js:131:1)
    at proto.update (index.js:109:1)
    at createShader (index.js:255:1)
    at Surface._makeShader (createSurface.js:538:1)
    at Surface._getShader (createSurface.js:547:1)
    at Node._getShader (Node.js:764:1)
    at Node._draw (Node.js:828:1)
    at Surface._draw (createSurface.js:590:1)
(
```

[image]

Here is a sandbox recreating the issue: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shadertest-mnle1f?file=/index.js).

I know for sure that the shader works because I have tested it, but can't make it work in React. The only library that I got to work was `react-three-fiber`, but I get other problems with that as well (see [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76077210/react-three-fiber-shader-uv-wrong-when-inside-component)).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `index.tsx` from:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")!;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

and now it works.